# OSX 10.9 alternative to ICMDecompressionSessionRef Deprecation and the like

Tags: avfoundation, osx-mavericks, video-capture, quicktime

What is the alternative to the functionality that is being deprecated in QuickTime.framework/ImageCompression.h in OSX 10.9?

Specifically:

```
ICMDecompressionSessionRef
ICMDecompressionTrackingCallbackRecord
ICMDecompressionSessionRelease
ImageDescriptionHandle::NewHandle
ICMDecompressionSessionCreate
DisposeHandle
ICMDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame
ICMDecompressionSessionSetNonScheduledDisplayTime
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the VideoToolbox Framework.